# css :before pseudo element + twitter bootstrap navbar logo

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pseudo-element

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap. This is a chunk of my header HTML:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">
    <span>watch.js</span>
</a>
```

I have also added following CSS:

```
.navbar-brand span:before {
  background: url("favicon.png")no-repeat;
  background-size: 53%;
}
```

I want to add a graphical logo in the navbar as a pseudo element (I believe it's easier to maintain on all devices rather than defining img elements along with styling them manually).

Unfortunately, the whole thing doesn't work, I mean, the `:before` pseudo element is not visible. It is even imposible to find using chrome dev tools. The image is there, but I guess that there is something else wrong with the CSS.

Can somebody please help me spot what shall I change in above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pseudo-elements like `::before` [need a `content` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) in order to become visible (e. g. `content:'';`). This renders a 0×0px box and you still have to set `width` and `height` on it. Maybe you’ll want to include `display` as well (e. g. `display:inline-block;`).

Your code needs to become at least

```css
.navbar-brand span::before {
  content:'';
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  dislay: inline-block;
  background: url("favicon.png")no-repeat;
  background-size: 53%;
}
```

(Note that pseudo-elements have two colons `::` instead of one `:` in CSS3 but backwards compatibility allows one as well.)

Comment: I've got one problem with the solution. When I write `content: "___"`, I do get an image in the background of the underscore chars. But when I write empty content, I get nothing (unvisible). What am I still missing?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz Okay, see my edit. I guess you needed to include `width` and `height` as well. Also try `display:inline-block` or something similar. I hope that resolves it.

Comment: yes, it helped. But styling this is tough as hell... The horizontal alignment gets broken all the time.